# Android ProgressBar setProgressDrawable stretches the vector drawable instead of repeating

Tags: android, android-progressbar, android-vectordrawable

I have the ff. vector drawable that I want to repeat based on the progress

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:height="6dp"
    android:viewportHeight="6"
    android:viewportWidth="10"
    android:width="10dp">

    <clip-path android:pathData="M 0 6 L 2.3 0 L 5 0 L 2.7 6 Z" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#E60000"
        android:pathData="M -5 -5 H 10 V 11 H -5 V -5 Z" />
    <clip-path android:pathData="M 4.9 6 L 7.2 0 L 9.9 0 L 7.6 6 Z" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#E60000"
        android:pathData="M -0.1 -5 H 14.9 V 11 H -0.1 V -5 Z" />
</vector>
```

However setProgressDrawable stretches the entire drawable.

```
progressBar.setProgressDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, getVectorDrawableRes()));
```

[image: stretches]

How do I repeat the above vector drawable instead of stretching it?

Comment: Have you tried `android:tileMode="repeat"` tag?

Comment: @Abhi tileMode doesn't work for vector unfortunately.